# Forecasting Daily Data using HoltWinters

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, holtwinters

First of all I have already consulted this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113819/r-holt-winters-with-daily-data-forecast-package) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210504/r-times-series-arima-model-forecasting-daily-data) but couldn't get it to work.

I have daily data starting from `28-03-2015` till `27-02-2017`.
My `TS object` looks like this:

```
bvg11_prod_ts <- ts(bvg11_data$MA_PROD, freq=365, start=c(2015, 87), end=c(2017, 58))
```

the below graph shows the daily values:

```
autoplot(bvg11_prod_ts)
```

[image]

I have also tried creating the daily ts object by:

```
bvg11_prod_ts <- ts(bvg11_data$MA_PROD, freq=7, start=c(2015, 3), end=c(2017, 02))
autoplot(bvg11_prod_ts)
```

which results in this plot:
[image]

As you can see both graphs are completely different, however, the first one is more accurate!

Now when i try to use the `bvg11_prodsTSHoltWinter <- HoltWinters(bvg11_prod_ts)` It gives error:

```
Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the lenght of your serie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: with a frequency of 365 you'll need at least 2*365 = 730 data points.

```
x_err = ts(runif(729), freq = 365)
# this gives an error
fit = HoltWinters(x_err)

# this will work
x = ts(runif(730), freq = 365)
fit = HoltWinters(x)
```